# NGINX 1.19 для ModX при настройке ЧПУ все страницы ведет на индекс

Tags: nginx, modx, чпу, php-fpm

На OpenServer пытаюсь разработать сайт на ModX 3.0.1 под nginx. Также важно выполнить настройку php-fpm.

В конфигурационном на сервере указал для настройки ЧПУ
`index  index.html index.php; try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;`

А при попытке настроить php-fpm сервер не подключается совсем

И теперь все страницы с ЧПУ открывают Главную,если эту настройку убрать, то 404 для любой.
Как исправить, чтобы на nginx работали ЧПУ на ModX?

Файл конфиг выглядит так:

```
# ----------------------------
# Host config
# ----------------------------

server {

listen                        %ip%:%httpport%;
listen                        %ip%:%httpsport% ssl http2;

server_name                   %host% %aliases%;
root                          '%hostdir%';
limit_conn                    addr 64;
autoindex                     off;
index                         index.php index.html index.htm;

ssl_certificate               '%sprogdir%/userdata/config/cert_files/server.crt';
ssl_certificate_key           '%sprogdir%/userdata/config/cert_files/server.key';
# ssl_trusted_certificate     '';

# Force HTTPS
# add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=2592000' always;
# if ($scheme ~* ^(?!https).*$) {
#    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
# }

# Force www.site.com => site.com
# if ($host ~* ^www\.(.+)$) {
#    return 301 $scheme://$1$request_uri;
# }

# Disable access to backup/config/command/log files
# if ($uri ~* ^.+\.(?:bak|co?nf|in[ci]|log|orig|sh|sql|tar|sql|t?gz|cmd|bat)$) {
#    return 404;
# }

# Disable access to hidden files/folders
if ($uri ~* /\.(?!well-known)) {
    return 404;
}

# Disable MIME sniffing
add_header X-Content-Type-Options 'nosniff' always;

location ~* ^.+\.(?:css(\.map)?|js(\.map)?|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|cur|heic|webp|tiff?|mp3|m4a|aac|ogg|midi?|wav|mp4|mov|webm|mpe?g|avi|ogv|flv|wmv|svgz?|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff2?)$ {
        expires 1d;
        access_log off;
}

location / {
    # Force index.php routing (if not found)
        index  index.html index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri$args;

    # Force index.php routing (all requests)
    # rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files      $fastcgi_script_name =404;

        # limit_conn   addr 16;
        # limit_req    zone=flood        burst=32 nodelay;

        # add_header   X-Frame-Options   'SAMEORIGIN' always;
        # add_header   Referrer-Policy   'no-referrer-when-downgrade' always;

        # CSP syntax: <host-source> <scheme-source>(http: https: data: mediastream: blob: filesystem:) 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'none'
        # Content-Security-Policy-Report-Only (report-uri https://site.com/csp/)
        # add_header   Content-Security-Policy  "default-src 'self'; connect-src 'self'; font-src 'self'; frame-src 'self'; img-src 'self'; manifest-src 'self'; media-src 'self'; object-src 'self'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; base-uri 'none'; form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'self'; upgrade-insecure-requests" always;

        fastcgi_pass   backend;
        include        '%sprogdir%/userdata/config/nginx_fastcgi_params.txt';
    }
}

# Service configuration (do not edit!)
# ----------------------------
location /openserver/ {
    root      '%sprogdir%/modules/system/html';
    autoindex off;
    index     index.php index.html index.htm;

    %allow%allow all;
    allow 127.0.0.0/8;
    allow ::1/128;
    allow %ips%;
    deny all;

    location ~* ^/openserver/.+\.(?:css(\.map)?|js(\.map)?|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|cur|heic|webp|tiff?|mp3|m4a|aac|ogg|midi?|wav|mp4|mov|webm|mpe?g|avi|ogv|flv|wmv|svgz?|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff2?)$ {
        expires 1d;
        access_log off;
    }

    location /openserver/server-status {
        stub_status on;
    }

    location ~ ^/openserver/.*\.php$ {
        try_files      $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_pass   backend;
        include        '%sprogdir%/userdata/config/nginx_fastcgi_params.txt';
    }
}
# End service configuration
# ----------------------------

}
# ----------------------------
# End host config
# ----------------------------
```

Содержание файла %sprogdir%/userdata/config/nginx_fastcgi_params.txt

```
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE      $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH    $content_length;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT     $document_root;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI      $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS             $https if_not_empty;
fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING      $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR       $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT       $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD    $request_method;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME    $scheme;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI       $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME   $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME       $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR       $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME       $host;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT       $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL   $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE   nginx;
```

Comment: При ЧПУ у вас не будет $args. Поэтому все ведет на главную index.php. Чтобы рекомендовать какую корректировку внести в Nginx покажите свой конфиг

Comment: Алексей, не знаю как это показать здесь. В поле комментов не помещается весь текст, а прикрепить файл не могу

Comment: отредактируйте свой вопрос https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1447131/edit

Comment: Спасибо, сделал

Comment: этот файл '%sprogdir%/userdata/config/nginx_fastcgi_params.txt' инклудируется в конфиг. Что в нем?

Comment: Алексей, через правку вопроса внес инфу

Answer (score 0):

Для начала MODX должен у вас работать и без ЧПУ, они уже включаются позже в Системных настройках через админку.
Посмотрите вот [эту страницу](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-install-modx-cms-and-nginx-on-centos-7/) (и [эту](https://docs.modx.com/current/ru/getting-started/friendly-urls/nginx) тоже) на предмет корректных настроек NGINX, мне кажется еще не доходя до MODX что-то настроено неверно.

Comment: Антон, с настройками конфига с этих страниц сервер не запускается вообще

Answer (score 0):

Измените location `location ~ \.php$` на:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;


        fastcgi_pass   backend;
        include        '%sprogdir%/userdata/config/nginx_fastcgi_params.txt';
    }
```

Comment: ПРописал, но все равно в дочерних папках и ссылках , типа, domain/page-1/ открывается главная. В общем, под всеми ссылками открывается главная

Comment: ваш backend корректно отрабатывает запросы вида  /index.php?q=/page-1/ ?

Comment: Да, без включения ЧПУ все работает отлично

Answer (score 0):

Изменил конфиг файл на такие настройки: (в изначальном помимо прочего была ошибка пунктуации)

```
# ----------------------------
# Host config
# ----------------------------

server {

listen                        %ip%:%httpport%;
listen                        %ip%:%httpsport% ssl http2;

server_name                   %host% %aliases%;
root                          '%hostdir%';
limit_conn                    addr 64;
autoindex                     off;
index                         index.php index.html index.htm;

ssl_certificate               '%sprogdir%/userdata/config/cert_files/server.crt';
ssl_certificate_key           '%sprogdir%/userdata/config/cert_files/server.key';
# ssl_trusted_certificate     '';

# Force HTTPS
# add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=2592000' always;
# if ($scheme ~* ^(?!https).*$) {
#    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
# }

# Force www.site.com => site.com
# if ($host ~* ^www\.(.+)$) {
#    return 301 $scheme://$1$request_uri;
# }

# Disable access to backup/config/command/log files
# if ($uri ~* ^.+\.(?:bak|co?nf|in[ci]|log|orig|sh|sql|tar|sql|t?gz|cmd|bat)$) {
#    return 404;
# }

# Disable access to hidden files/folders
if ($uri ~* /\.(?!well-known)) {
    return 404;
}

# Disable MIME sniffing
add_header X-Content-Type-Options 'nosniff' always;

location ~* ^.+\.(?:css(\.map)?|js(\.map)?|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|cur|heic|webp|tiff?|mp3|m4a|aac|ogg|midi?|wav|mp4|mov|webm|mpe?g|avi|ogv|flv|wmv|svgz?|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff2?)$ {
        expires 1d;
        access_log off;
}
 location @modx-rewrite {
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1&$args last;
 }
location / {
    
    absolute_redirect off;
            try_files $uri $uri/ @modx-rewrite;
}
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files      $fastcgi_script_name =404;

        fastcgi_pass   backend;
        include        '%sprogdir%/userdata/config/nginx_fastcgi_params.txt';
    }


# Service configuration (do not edit!)
# ----------------------------
location /openserver/ {
    root      '%sprogdir%/modules/system/html';
    autoindex off;
    index     index.php index.html index.htm;

    %allow%allow all;
    allow 127.0.0.0/8;
    allow ::1/128;
    allow %ips%;
    deny all;

    location ~* ^/openserver/.+\.(?:css(\.map)?|js(\.map)?|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|cur|heic|webp|tiff?|mp3|m4a|aac|ogg|midi?|wav|mp4|mov|webm|mpe?g|avi|ogv|flv|wmv|svgz?|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff2?)$ {
        expires 1d;
        access_log off;
    }

    location /openserver/server-status {
        stub_status on;
    }

    location ~ ^/openserver/.*\.php$ {
        try_files      $fastcgi_script_name =404;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_pass   backend;
        include        '%sprogdir%/userdata/config/nginx_fastcgi_params.txt';
    }
}
# End service configuration
# ----------------------------

}
# ----------------------------
# End host config
# ----------------------------
```